# How to show that if $\mathbb{E}(X^4) < \infty$, then $\mathbb{E}(X^2) < \infty$?

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance, jensen-inequality

Let $\mu = \mathbb{E}X$ and $\sigma ^2 = Var(X)$ and $X_1, ..., X_n$ a sample. How do I show that if $\mathbb{E}(X^4) < \infty$, then $\mathbb{E}(X^2) < \infty$ using Jensen's inequality?

Comment: $x\rightarrow x^2$ is convex, try applying Jensen inequality with this function and $X^2$.

Comment: Do you mean that $\mathbb{E}[X^4] = \mathbb{E}[(X^2)^2] \geq [\mathbb{E}X^2]^2$?

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much a direct application of Jensen's inequality. Let $g(x)=x^2$ and $\varphi(x)=x^2$. Then $\varphi$ is convex so by Jensen's inequality,
$$
\varphi \left(\int_\Omega g \mathrm{d}\mu\right)\leq \int_\Omega \varphi \circ g\,\mathrm{d}\mu \
$$
which shows $[E(X^2)]^2\leq E[X^4]<\infty.$

Comment: Okay so showing $[E(X^2)]^2 \leq E[X^4]$ also implies $E[X^2] \leq E[X^4]$, because I was not sure about that.

Comment: No; I think I see the confusion. A number is finite if and only if its square is finite. You're not showing $E[X^2]\leq E[X^4],$ just that $E[X^2]$ is finite.